# What is the difference between these two methods? They both look the same but each method leads to different outputs

Tags: java, methods, parameters, this

First method:

```
public PointMover (Point p)
{

    this.p = p;
    homePoint = new Point (p.x, p.y);


}
```

Second method:

```
public PointMover (Point p)
{

    this.p = p;
    homePoint = p; 

}
```

At first I though that for both methods, homePoint will get the x and y value of Point p. Turns out that's not the case. I have a very long code with me. When I use the first method in the code, I get one output from the program. When I use the second method in the code instead of the first one, I get an entirely different output from the program. So what is the difference between these 2 methods? What is the role of homePoint in these methods?

Thank you.

Comment: The first one creates a **new instance** of **Point** and assigns it to **homePoint**, so changes made in the **Point** passed to the method (the constructor) doesn't affect your **homePoint**.

Comment: Those are constructors, not methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in the first method, `homePoint` is a new Object, so changing the coordinates of the argument `p` will not have any effect on the field `homePoint`.

In the second method however, `homePoint` points to the given argument `p`. If, outside of the method, you change anything to the parameter `p`, this will also be reflected in `homePoint`.

The code below exemplifies the difference

**Example code**

```
public class Test {
    public Point homePoint;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p = new Point(4, 3);
        Test test = new Test();

        System.out.println("test1:");
        test.test1(p);
        System.out.println("home point : " + test.homePoint);
        System.out.println("p          : " + p);
        p.x = 8;
        System.out.println("home point : " + test.homePoint);
        System.out.println("p          : " + p);

        System.out.println("test2:");
        test.test2(p);
        System.out.println("home point : " + test.homePoint);
        System.out.println("p          : " + p);
        p.x = 4;
        System.out.println("home point : " + test.homePoint);
        System.out.println("p          : " + p);


    }

    public void test1(Point point) {
        homePoint = new Point(point.x, point.y);
    }

    public void test2(Point point) {
        homePoint = point;
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
test1:
home point : java.awt.Point[x=4,y=3]
p          : java.awt.Point[x=4,y=3]
home point : java.awt.Point[x=4,y=3]
p          : java.awt.Point[x=8,y=3]
test2:
home point : java.awt.Point[x=8,y=3]
p          : java.awt.Point[x=8,y=3]
home point : java.awt.Point[x=4,y=3]
p          : java.awt.Point[x=4,y=3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one creates a new Point, with the same coordinates as the argument `p`, and assigns it to `this.p`. If you change the state of one point, it won't affect the other one, since you made a copy.

The second one assigns the argument `p` to `this.p`. The caller and the PointMover both refer to the exact same object. If the caller modifies the state of the point, the PointMover's point state will also change, since you have a single object. And if the PointMover changes the state of the point, the caller's point state will also change, since you have a single object.